# How to give a user access only three sites and other all sites is blocked by mikrotik router?

Tags: router

**Mikrotik router Model :450g**

like as,Access lists :

1.www.google.com

2.www.yahoo.com

3.www.banglalinkgsm.com

Denny list :
All sites without access listed sites .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can follow this procedure:**

Use Firewall > Filter Rules.

***For www.google.com access :***

1.add a new rule

2.chain: forward

3.Src.Address : LAN Network IP

4.Dst.Address: www.google.com

5.in.Interface : LAN Port Name

6.action: accept

7.apply >OK

***For www.yahoo.com access :***

1.add a new rule

2.chain: forward

3.Src.Address : LAN Network IP

4.Dst.Address: www.yahoo.com

5.in.Interface : LAN Port Name

6.action: accept

7.apply >OK

***For www.banglalinkgsm.com access :***

1.add a new rule

2.chain:forward

3.Src.Address : LAN Network IP

4.Dst.Address: www.banglalinkgsm.com

5.in.Interface : LAN Port Name

6.action: accept

7.apply >OK

***For Other sites access :***

1.add a new rule

2.chain: forward

3.in.Interface : LAN Port Name

4.action: drop

5.apply >OK

Comment: In RouterOS impossible to use host names in firewall rules. Only IPs.
It good solution, if You can build list of allowed IPs. But google and yahoo use changing pols of adresses.

Comment: first he/she need to trace the host ip then give the ip access.otherwise he/she can use layer7 rule and call the rule name .

Answer (score 0):

The solution described above does not work, because www.google.com does not have fixe IP address.

Solution is this:
https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Use_host_names_in_firewall_rules

Comment: Link-only answers are _highly_ discouraged because the links can go bad. Please include the relevant text in your answer, and provide a link to the original to give proper attribution.